# How to simplify this summation expression

Tags: summation

The expression is:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} 1 - \Bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{n} 2^{-k/2}\Bigg)^2 $$

I know that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} 1 = 1n $$

I don't really know how to proceed with the latter part.

Comment: You have a geometric series

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} 2^{-k/2}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^k,$$
which is a [geometric series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html) (see Eq. 8). Can you take it from here? If not, please do let me know.

Comment: Would this change if the sum went to infinity instead of n?

Comment: @RyanSmith Yes, see Eq. 9.

Comment: @Lovesovs i'm not entirely sure which one it should be actually. I asked another question with the full problem if you're interested http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1976443/finding-the-expected-value-and-the-variance?noredirect=1#comment4057210_1976443

Comment: @RyanSmith Please don't just repeat an already existing question. From what you write ($k=1,2,3,\dots$), it seems $k$ runs from $1$ to $\infty$, but this also means that your variance is infinite.