# Finding the expected value and the variance

Tags: probability, statistics

Say $X$ is a variable with the value $2^{k/2}$ and with a probability of ${1/2^k}$ where $k = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$

I want to find the expected value of X and the variance.

I know $\operatorname{E}(x) = x \cdot \Pr(X = x)$. From this I got: $$\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{-k/2}$$

The formula for variance is: $$\operatorname{V}(X) = \operatorname{E}(X^2) - [\operatorname{E}(X)]^2$$

To find the first part I did: $$\operatorname{E}(X^2) = x^2\cdot \Pr(X = x) = \sum_{k=1}^n 1$$

So $$\operatorname{V}(X) = \operatorname{E}(X^2) - [\operatorname{E}(X)]^2$$ $$=\sum_{k=1}^n 1 - \left(\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{-k/2}\right)^2 $$

This is where I get stuck on simplifying the expression. How would I continue?

Comment: It $n$ finite or infinite?  The expectation is a geometric series simplifying to $1+\sqrt{2}$ when $n$ is infinite,  while the second moment would clearly be unbounded.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^{n} 2^{-k/2} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} (\frac {\sqrt 2}{2})^{k}$ which is a geometric series, and you should have a formula for the sum.  And $\sum_{k=1}^n 1 = n$ so the variance goes to infinity as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: @Henry i'm not entirely sure. Most formulas just have a $$\sum$$ symbol. Does that mean n or infinity?

Comment: @RyanSmith When a bare $\sum$ is used, it means sum over all possible values of the bound variable (which is implicitly identified).  More typically the bound variable is explicitly identified (as $\sum_k$ or such).  In this case, the support of the pmf is ${[1;\infty)\cap\Bbb N}$, so it goes to infinity.